# Perimeter of a kite

Tags: geometry

For kite ABCD, AB=x/6+5,AD=x/3+3 and BC=x-2, find the perimeter of  kite ABCD. How do I find the perimeter, I've tried equaling AB to AD but I get the answer to be 2, and when I substitute it into the equations I get a fraction.

Comment: How did you get 2 and how did you know that AB equals AD?

Comment: I know that AB is congruent to AD because it states it in the book, so I tried to equal it to each other and I get 2 or a weird answer, also side DC is missing an eqa

Comment: Missing an equation so I would say is the same as BC since both are congruent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two side of the kite are equal.
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help ☺

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{x}{6}+5=\frac{x}{3}+3$$
$$5-3=\frac{x}{3}-\frac{x}{6}$$
$$2=\frac{x}{6}$$

$$x=12$$

With this value of $x$, can you find the perimeter?

Comment: How do you know that AB equals AD?

Comment: That is a possibility, the other possibility is to let $AB=BC$